# Mass select options

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a list of comma separated values "1,2,3,4"
I have a multiselect list with options that match those values, I am cycling through my list and selecting each option individually(see below)

```
jQuery.each(selectedVals, function(index, item){
     jQuery("option[value='"+item+"']", jQuery("#manage select")).attr('selected', true);
});
```

The multiselect list and the values could be in the hundreds so the performance on older browsers is slow when cycling through and selecting.  Is there a quicker way to accomplish this?  Some how selecting them all at once?

Comment: Use `.prop('selected', true)` instead of `.attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Start by caching your queried objects, and see if you actually have performance problems. You shouldn't be doing something like `jQuery("#manage select")` in a loop; you should store that value so you don't have to continually go back to the DOM to find an element you've already found previously:

```
var $manage = jQuery("#manage select");

jQuery.each(selectedVals, function(index, item){
     $manage.find("option[value='"+item+"']").prop('selected', true);
});
```

You're still querying the DOM once per loop however. You might also find a huge performance improvement by simply finding *all* `<options>` inside your `#manage` container, and then manually filtering them one by one:

```
var $options = jQuery("#manage select option");

jQuery.each(selectedVals, function (index, item){
  $options.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('value') == $item) {
      $(this).prop('selected', true)
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I understand the concept, due to some implementation restrictions on the template layer this isn't possible.  I was looking for a fundamental way to do this different not an improvement.

Comment: Yes, see the second option. Just select them all with `#manage select option` and filter the list down manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this much faster by passing an array of values into .val() instead of setting each option as selected.

Answer (score -1):

Use: `.prop('checked', true);` in order to check multiple checkboxes at once.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MB4rk/)